# Cocos2d-x setContentSize gives poor graphic quality

Tags: graphics, cocos2d-x, sprite, screen-resolution

I want to create sprite with size is relative to the screen size.
I.e: Sprite size is equal to screen width * 0.2.

I use `setContentSize` and `setScale` but it gives ugly and poor graphic quality.
I've read about multiple resolution supports, but it doesn't work on this case because i need sprite size adapt to the any screen size.

Testing on iPhone 7, i scale an image from 512x512 to 64x64.

This is error of cocos2d-x or anyway to archive it?

Answer (score 0):

Scale it accordingly to a device size.

```
yourSprite->setScale(mainScene->getContentSize().width / yourSprite->getContentSize().width * 0.2, mainScene->getContentSize().width / yourSprite->getContentSize().width * 0.2);
```

And do not use `setContentSize`

Comment: `setScale` makes same result as `setContentSize`

Comment: @TomSawyer maybe you are putting that sprite to another sprite which have small image size?

Comment: Nope, i create individual sprite. And i found out that this error only happend on real divice (i'm using iPhone 7). Using `setScale` instead of `setContentSize` can solve this trouble on simulator.

Comment: have you experienced the same? I'm stucking here, the only way is creating multiple versions of sprite for different sizes?

Comment: No I have not experienced issues with scalling. Can you post how you create the sprite and where you add it?

Comment: I've done numerous of queries and this trouble is exist: you can see the topic here: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/sprite-border-looks-like-not-anti-aliased-after-rotation-or-downscaling/10623 http://esotericsoftware.com/forum/Aliased-Sprites-on-Scale-CCD2X-5337 down scaling creates aliasing on sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your sprite according content scale factor that calculates according to your device screen size and what ResolutionPolicy you're using.

```
auto sprite= Sprite::create("xyz.png")
sprite->setScale(Director::getInstance()->getContentScaleFactor());
```

Comment: I've tried with `setScale` but the result is the same with `setContentSize`. It only work if the size of image close to the target size like 150->32 is ok, but 512->32 will be really bad.

Comment: for major variation(512->32) in size you need to create resources in different size/resolution, and set path to that resources according to device resolution. it is an ideal solution. It's obvious if we scale up or down in any amount, we are decreasing quality of resource.

Comment: Scaling up decrease graphic quality, but scaling from big to small must preserve the quality. You can see the image here: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/setcontentsize-gives-poor-graphic/36606/2 I figure out that i have this trouble only on real divice (iPhone 7), testing on iPhone 6 simulator with `setScale` and it's good. Is this a bug of cocos?

Comment: Scaling in any way up/down, quality of image degraded according to scaling extent. In your link you scale first image `512->32` so scale factor is `.0625` and another one is `64->32` and so scale factor is `.5` . More extent of scaling(up/down) decrease more quality of that image.

Comment: I don't know what cocos does on scaling, but any resize image mechanism on any language can give a acceptable quality while scaling from bigger to smaller. Resize 2048 to 32 get the same result as 64 to 32.

Comment: no dear I've quite good experience on LibGDX, there also facing same problem so need to apply filter on texture `myTexture.setFilter(Textue.TextureFilter.Linear, Textue.TextureFilter.Linear);`

Comment: Anyway to do it on cocos2d-x? or workaround :(? Creating numberous sprite with different sizes is not a good option i want. Resizing image is really basic thing need to be done but i don't think it's hard to archive like this.

Comment: I've done the way to apply filter to make scaled sprite looks smooth, but it also blurry using mipmaping. Itsn't what i want. I think the best way to solve it is resize/downscale by some good image processing algorithm the image from the beginning and let sprite use it.

Comment: From where I get such algorithms ?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570895/image-downscaling-algorithm . I'm finding how to import and use it inside LibGDX or Cocos2d-x